# Let $a$ belong to a ring R. Let $S=\{x \in R | ax=0\}$. Show that S is a subring of R.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a$ belong to a ring R. Let $S=\{x \in R | ax=0\}$. Show that S is a subring of R.

My approach is such:

Let $c,d \in S$ so $(c-d)x=cx-dx=0-0=0 and (cd)x=(cx)d=(0)d=0$. Therefore by the subring test, S is a subring of R. Q.E.D

Is this correct or not so much?

Comment: I suggest you to write $a(cd)=(ac)d=0d=0$. Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: You should also prove that $S$ is non-empty.

Comment: In fact, more than beinga subring, it is a right ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn’t look carefully enough at the definition of $S$: $a$ is a fixed element of $R$, and to show that some $r\in R$ belongs to $S$, you must show that $ar=0$.

Suppose that $x,y\in S$. Then $a(x-y)=ax-ay=0-0=0$, so $x-y\in S$. Can you finish up by showing correctly that if $x,y\in S$, then $xy\in S$? (And remember, you can’t assume that $R$ is commutative, as you did in the step $(cd)x=c(xd)$ in your first attempt.)

Comment: So would the last step be $a(xy)=(ax)y=(0)y=0$?

Comment: @Whyser: Yes, that’s exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

frist,we show S is nonempty subset of R.
since 0 belongs S therefore S is non empty.
now,
let a,b belongs to S  ,then
(a-b)x=ax-bx=0 
and
(ab)x=ax*bx=0  [ ¥  x € R]
hence (a-b) and (ab) belongs to S 
then by subring test S is a subring of R.